# Is it possible to read from a url into a System.IO.Stream object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, io, iostream

I am attempting to read from a url into a System.IO.Stream object.  I tried to use

```
Dim stream as Stream = New FileStream(msgURL, FileMode.Open)
```

but I get an error that URI formats are not supported with FileStream objects.  Is there some method I can use that inherits from System.IO.Stream that is able to read from a URL?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

VB.Net:

```
Dim req As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("url here")
Using stream As Stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()

End Using
```

C#:

```
var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("url here");
using (Stream stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{

}
```

Comment: Using this code I wasn't able to deserialize the content on the other end of the web request.  I suggest using Thomas Levesque's answer below, as it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 36):

Use `WebClient.OpenRead` :

```
Using wc As New WebClient()
    Using stream As Stream = wc.OpenRead(msgURL)
        ...
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know OpenRead existed. I'll remember that one.

Comment: I didn't know either... I just guessed something like that existed, and checked in MSDN library ;)

Comment: Of course the simplest way... Add code to show closing of the stream and disposing of the web client, and it's just perfect. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a HttpWebRequest object to get a response stream:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// read the stream
receiveStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

(Stripped down and simplifed from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx)).